# Does ProgrammableWeb itself have a web-service API?

Tags: web-services

I was wondering if anyone knows if [ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com) has a service-API, (such as REST), in order to query the repository for information about other services/apps that are published to the website?

Or perhaps even a 3rd-party one, that I so far haven’t been able to find?

If it doesn’t, does anyone know of other services/apps repositories that have APIs where information on the stored services can be retrieved? Such as the ratings by users, tags, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.

http://api.programmableweb.com/

Comment: Its now broken, does they still have an api?